# How to use sql query to find percentage on the basis of certain conditions?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

please consider the table below for reference

| student name | class | marks | total marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | 10-B | 50 | 100 |
| Leo | 10-B | 20 | 200 |
| Cris | 11-B | 23 | 150 |
| Lynn | 10-B | 100 | 240 |
| Rachel | 11-B | 210 | 500 |
| Ronda | 9-B | 43 | 400 |

So what I want to do is to calculate the percentage for each row but not simply by dividing `marks/total marks *100` But I want to calculate the percentage on the class level i.e. for `class 10-B` the percentage will be `(50+20+100)/(100+200+240)*100`, So here I want the percentage on class level and display that in each row. So I want the resultant table like as follows:

| student name | class | marks | total marks | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | 10-B | 50 | 100 | 20 |
| Leo | 10-B | 20 | 200 | 20 |
| Cris | 11-B | 23 | 150 | 40 |
| Lynn | 10-B | 100 | 240 | 20 |
| Rachel | 11-B | 210 | 500 | 40 |
| Ronda | 9-B | 43 | 400 | 10 |

*percentage are just for reference and not calculated correctly.

So here you can see each class has same percentage.

Also, I am using standard sql in bigquery

Comment: Please remove tags of databases that you do not use

Comment: BigQuery has both legacy SQL and standard SQL, you may want to specify which you're using.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Standard sql

Comment: Don't have BigQuery to test on at the moment, but standard SQL should work with something like `SELECT *, 100* AVG("marks") OVER (PARTITION BY class) / AVG("total marks") OVER (PARTITION BY class) percentage FROM students` (with appropriate quoting of the column names of course, afaik can't use backtick in comments)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It worked, Thanks, Also we can use ```sum()``` instead of ```AVG()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want window functions:

```
select t.*,
       ( sum(marks) over (partition by class) * 100.0 / 
         sum(total_marks) over (partition by class)
       ) as class_ratio
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to see the individual students if all you care about is class percentage?

```
SELECT Class, AVG(marks * 1. / total marks) AS Percentage
FROM     dbo.ClassTbl
GROUP BY Class
```

Also Percent is a Float (1 = 100%) so the multiplier handles it because your values are Int and SQL sees that and thinks the result will also be an Int.

Unless you just want the individuals results

```
SELECT Class, student name, marks * 1. / total marks AS Percentage
FROM     dbo.ClassTbl
```

Also as a side note TableTitles should be CamelCase no spaces.